# water heater circuit requires a ground connection

Tags: water, grounding, heater

Purchased a British Standard water heater with 3 supply connections -live, neutral and earth. The circuit design requires a ground. Tried to fix the water heater in Philippines which only has 2 pin supply connection. Although the water heater could work *tested with elcb switch etc) , it has a built in safety alarm system that require the water heater to be grounded. Tried connecting the ground wire from the equipment to a water pipe but it did not work.
How do you connect a ground to the water heater circuit  with a two-pin supply line ?

Comment: Is your power delivered as "old style" (2 hots, no neutral or ground), or "new style" (hot and neutral, with or without a ground)?

Comment: It may not play in the Philippines.  Often there, ground is 120V away from both hots, and safety circuits may not like that.